# Backup oracle graph

Tags: oracle-graph

We are using PG views for the graph. Currently is looking for the easiest way to backup or transfer data.

How can we backup existing graph or anyways to transfer/duplicate to another server?

Any solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PG views are composed of regular database tables, you can apply all existing methods for export/import, such as Oracle Data Pump (expdp/impdp). Please note you need to include or re-create the metadata tables.

- If you export/import **the schema**, the metadata tables should be included with the data source tables.
- If you export/import **selected tables**, you can include the meta tables or re-create them after the import. Re-creating option is more robust when the metadata table definition is updated between the product versions.

Metadata Tables for PG Views:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/22.1/spgdg/property-graph-views-oracle-database-tables.html